# Use get_the_tag_list outside loop

Tags: wordpress

I´m trying to use get_the_tag_list outside the loop to display all tags used on the current page. I want to use

```
<?php echo get_the_tag_list('<div>
Tags: 
 <li class="*tagslug*">', '</div>'); ?>
```

and also put the tag slug as class. Is this possible to do outside of the loop.

I´ve also tried this

```
<?php $tag = wp_tag_cloud('format=array' );
    foreach($tag as $tagkey => $tagvalue)
        {
        $cleanedup = strip_tags($tagvalue);
        echo "<li class='".$cleanedup."'>".$cleanedup."</li>";
        }
?>
```

It pretty much does it for what i want to display, but I want to return the slug as the class.

Am I on the right path or just walking in circles?

Comment: I think you'd be better off using [get_the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags).

Comment: Sorry, but I´m quite new to php, if I understand correct  `<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags($id);
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
?>` shall list all tags i currently have used on my page (using the code outside of the loop) I dont get it to work